# LWC (Lightning Web Component) Convert Lead Via Apex and return Account Id

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, leads, lead-conversion

I would like to call a custom APEX Class that converts a lead. I have successfully been able to create the LWC, Call the Apex Class, & Convert the lead. I am having trouble returning the new Account Id & Contact Id to the LWC to then handle redirects and other post create/convert actions.

Here is the APEX CLASS:

```
public class AutoConvertLeads {  
   @AuraEnabled
   Public static id doConvert(Id leadId){

        System.debug('doConvert LeadId: ' + leadId);
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(leadId);
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(True);
        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('doConvert ConvertStatus: ' + convertStatus);
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        System.debug('doConvert LeadConvertResult: ' + lcr);

        id accountId = lcr.getAccountId();
        id contactId = lcr.getcontactId();

        System.debug('doConvert AccountId Result: ' + accountId);
        System.debug('doConvert ContactId Result: ' + contactId);

        return accountId;
    }
}
```

When checking debug logs I am able to see that the Account Id & Contact Id are being set and are correct.

Here is the JS for the LWC:

```
// Lead Convert Functionality
convert(){

console.log('Convert Button was Clicked!');
console.log('Record Id:');
console.log(this.recordId);

leadConvert({leadId : this.recordId})
    .then(result => {

        console.log('Convert Result:');
        console.log(result);

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('There was an Error :( ...');
        this.error = error;
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Any assistance you can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning just the Id, return a **map** instead

```
 @AuraEnabled
   public static Map<String,String> doConvert(Id leadId){

    System.debug('doConvert LeadId: ' + leadId);
    Map<String,Id> mapResult = new Map<String,Id>();
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(leadId);
    lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(True);
    LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
    System.debug('doConvert ConvertStatus: ' + convertStatus);
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
    System.debug('doConvert LeadConvertResult: ' + lcr);

    id accountId = lcr.getAccountId();
    id contactId = lcr.getcontactId();

    mapResult.put('accountId', accountId);

    mapResult.put('contactId', contactId);

    System.debug('doConvert AccountId Result: ' + accountId);
    System.debug('doConvert ContactId Result: ' + contactId);

    return mapResult;
}
```